# How to put background image to a text field and text view in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextfield, uitextview

Although I have set the background image property in `UITextField`. It doesn't apply.I didn't use any coding. I have just selected an `image.png` file as the backround image using Interface Builder. So,How to do it ?
And there is no background image property in `UITextView`. So,How can I add background image to `textView` ?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you set your `UITextField`'s background color to clear color?

Comment: No.I didn't set it.Do I need to set it ?Thank u very much.I'll try it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation of UITextField and you will find the following:

The default value for this property is UITextBorderStyleNone. If the value is set to the UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect style, the custom background image associated with the text field is ignored.

In Interface Builder, just below the place where you set the background image, there should be an option to select a border style, by default it is selected to RoundedRect, select another style and you can immediately see the background image.

Comment: Set the backgroundColor of UItextField as clearcolor. Place an UIImageView with the image exactly underneath the UITextField

Answer (score 6):

Use this

```
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:myImage];
```

where "myImage" is your image.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

First one, add the image to your `Assets.xcassets` with the name you want, like `myImage`. In your textfield, you can set it with:

```
myTextField.background = UIImage(named: "myImage")
```

Also, if you want to remove the borders:

```
myTextField.layer.borderColor = CGColor.clear
myTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set TextView backGround image using

```
[textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]]];
```

And for yourTextField you can set image using 2 method first is previous and other is

```
[textField setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(30, 130,160, 30);
textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame1];
textField.borderStyle =UITextBorderStyleNone;
textField.background=[UIImage imageNamed:@"textFieldImage.png"];
```

Comment: Some explanation to the Code for OP to understand it would be nice.

Answer (score -2):

To add a background image to views that have no background image property, you will need to do some trickery.  You will need to create a UIImageView and then add the UITextView as a subview.  Make sure the UITextView background color is set to clear as well. For example:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithimage:myImage];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView addSubview:myTextView];
```

Comment: i didnt tried this , it may work but not correct approach